# Ansible Parse JSON Array from Register

Tags: arrays, json, ansible, ansible-inventory

*Related Post: [ansible parse json array reply from api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941217/ansible-parse-json-array-reply-from-api)*

I have an Ansible playlist which registers a return variable:

```
- name: Create Instance
ec2_instance:
  aws_access_key: "{{access_key}}"
  aws_secret_key: "{{secret_key}}"
  key_name: ***
  instance_type: t2.micro
  security_group: ***
  image_id: ami-39f8215b
  region: ***
register: details
```

So the `details` is a JSON object like this:

```
{
"details": {
    "changed": false, 
    "changes": [], 
    "failed": false, 
    "instance_ids": [
        "i-1111abcde"
    ],
...
}
```

All I want to do is write a text file with each `instance_id` in there:

```
i-1111abcde
```

I've tried all of the following, none working:

```
debug:
  var: item
with_items: details['instance_ids']

debug:
  var: item.item
with_items: details['instance_ids']

debug:
  var: details.instance_ids
with_items: details
# This works, but prints the entire JSON array...
```

**Solution**

```
- name: Debug Info
debug:
  var: item
loop: "{{details.instance_ids}}"

- name: Write Temp File
lineinfile:
  path: /tmp/temp.txt
  line: "{{ item }}"
loop: "{{ details.instance_ids }}"
```

Note: `loop` is a more modern Ansible concept that `with_items` or `with_*`

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
- name: Debug Info
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{details.instance_ids}}"

- name: Write Temp File
lineinfile:
  path: /tmp/temp.txt
  line: "{{ item }}"
loop: "{{ details.instance_ids }}"
```

Note: loop is a more modern Ansible concept that with_items or with_*